# jquery each return array number instead of an actual object

Tags: jquery, node-crawler

I have this jquery code using [node-crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler)

```
 $('#selector img[src*="http://domainname.com/images"]')
        .each((x) => {
          console.log(x);
        });
```

The code print numbers from 0....n but I want to access the object value, how would you do that? Say I want to access the `src` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery each callback function actually takes 2 parameters.  The first one is the array index, the second one is the item.

```
$('#selector img[src*="http://domainname.com/images"]')
    .each((index, item) => {
      console.log(item);
    });
```

reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/